# Job types other than Permanent and Contract

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

In the search bar there is an option to filter Job type and lists two Options apart from "any". So if the job doesn't fall in one of the two categories what does it fall into?

When a job is posted, the job type isn't a necessary field?

When I filter the results based on job type I get 0 results for Contract and 89 results for Permanent. And "any" job type returns 99 results. So into which category do the remaining 10 jobs fall into? Is it that a job can be in none of the categories?

Comment: Umm..'secure and well-paid'?

Comment: or possibly, my job.

Comment: so lets say then a permenant job isnt secure and well payed. And this filter should be made available. i am looking for a secured well paid job :)

Comment: I'm the last person to help with that:(

Comment: Now, there is "Full-time", "Contract" and "Internship". I guess "Permanent" was replaced by "Full-time"? By the way, I found an interesting freelancer (contract) job that was in the "Permanent" category. So if you filter job types, you may miss opportunities if they have the wrong category.

Answer (score 3):

That field isn't mandatory. Employers can simply leave it as "unspecified", which would cause they strangeness you see.